# Showing the name of logged user

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, authentication

I have a specific situation. My home page looks like this :

http://prntscr.com/8hpccw

The thing i need is to show user's name when i login, but for my assignment i had to make class `User` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{

public class User
{

    public string Username
    {

        get;
        set;

    }

    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void getAll()
    {

        DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.usersTableAdapter usersTableAdapters = new DataSet1TableAdapters.usersTableAdapter();
        DataSet1.usersDataTable usersDataTable = new DataSet1.usersDataTable();
        usersDataTable = usersTableAdapters.GetData();
        return;
    }
    public void checkUser()
    {


        DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=JOVAN-PC;database=aukcija_jovan_gajic;integrated security=true;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users where name='" + Username + "'and password='" + Password + "'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string user = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

and then connect it to `Login` page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Focus();
        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username.");
                TextBox1.Focus();
            }

            else if (TextBox2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password.");
                TextBox2.Focus();
            }

            else
            {

                string username = TextBox1.Text;
                string password = TextBox2.Text;

                User u = new User();
                u.Username = username;
                u.Password = password;
                u.checkUser();

                MessageBox.Show("Log in succesfull!");
                Response.Redirect("http://localhost:11424/Home.aspx");
}
}
}
```

Now, i assume i should write something in `User` class after `string user = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();` but i don't what.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` in an ASP.NET web app?

Comment: It looks more like a WPF app than web app, but professor asked specifically to be done like this. Don't ask me why. I know how to do this in WPF, but not sure about web app.

Comment: I know the proper way, don't worry. Anyway, do you have any idea about my problem? I'm not very good with ASP.NET, is there any way to rewrite solution without breaking too much of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have so much wrong with your question, it's hard to know where to start. But let's break it down.

You have `using System.Windows.Forms;`. You should practically never need the Windows Forms namespace in an ASP.NET app. Get rid of that line.

You have a function `User.getAll()`. Prepending the verb "get" to a member name typically denotes that it will return something. But you've declared that method as void. It should probably return the `usersDataTable` object and the signature should be `public DataTable GetAllUsersDataTable()`.

Speaking of which, your example never shows `User.getAll()` being called. So don't include it in your question. Including it violates the "minimal" part of providing a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your `User.checkUser` method's name implies that it's merely checking whether the user is valid. Therefore, it shouldn't also log the user in. That's called the single responsibility principle. So the easiest thing to do is change the signature to `public bool IsLoginValid()` and have the method return a boolean value indicating whether the login attempt was successful or not.

`User.checkUser` should also probably be a static method, and instead of utilizing properties for the username/password, it should probably accept them as parameters instead.

Within the `User.checkUser` function, you're misusing [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable` interface, therefore you need to make sure it gets disposed of properly so that the connection isn't left open. Simply calling `SqlConnection.Close` later in the code isn't sufficient, because you need to ensure that the method is reached. If you use a `using` statement, it will ensure that the close method gets called for you.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(arguments etc))
{
    //Use the connection in here
}
```

Your database is storing the passwords in plaintext. While in an academic setting that's fine, because real people's passwords won't be exposed. But it's an extraordinarily bad habit to get into. Passwords should be one-way hashed, and salted. This makes it difficult for bad people to retrieve a user's real password. It may be an academic environment, but security is something you *must* take seriously if you go on to do this in the real world.

Another huge security issue, inside `User.checkUser` you're concatenating strings into your database query. That leaves you extremely vulnerable to an [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Programmers that get in this bad habit are one the reasons this attack is so prevalent in the real world. The defense against that in .NET is to [parameterize your database commands](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/).

Within the `User.checkUser` function, if the database lookup fails, you call `Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);`. I'm not sure what the effects of that are in ASP.NET, but my guess is that it will crash the server. Not good. Instead like I mentioned earlier, that method should return a boolean indicating whether the login succeeded or not. That would be a good place to `return false;`.

Now onto your Login page. Again, you're `using System.Windows.Forms`. Don't do that. The `MessageBox` class you're utilizing would open a message box *on the server*. While that's fine when the client and server are the same, that's almost never the case outside of local testing. Don't get in a bad habit now. Learn to use JavaScript to pop up a dialog on the client. Replace all your `MessageBox` calls with something like this:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
    "unique key identifying the script",
    "alert('Message here!');",
    true);
```

Like I said earlier, `User.checkUser` should return a boolean indicating successful login or not. So now we should handle that in our login page. Change `u.checkUser();` to something like this:

```
bool successfulLogin = u.checkUser();
if(successfulLogin)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx"); //notice we do root relative, so that if the host changes we don't have to change the string
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
        "loginFailure",
        "alert('Invalid login attempt!');",
        true);
}
```

Now for the part where I directly answer your question. You need a way of associating a session with the correct user. The best place to store that is in the `Session` variable.

```
Session["Username"] = username;
```

After all that, I've created a cleaned up version of your code that follows most of the advice I gave. Starting with the user class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class UserManager
    {
        public static bool IsLoginValid(string username, string password)
        {
            var dataSet1 = new DataSet1();          
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users where name=@Username and password=@Password");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=JOVAN-PC;database=aukcija_jovan_gajic;integrated security=true;"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }                                               
            if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the login page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                UsernameTB.Focus();
            }
        }

        protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UsernameTB.Text))
            {
                AddStartupAlert("MissingUsername", "Please enter your username.");
                UsernameTB.Focus();
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordTB.Text))
            {
                AddStartupAlert("MissingPassword", "Please enter your password.");
                PasswordTB.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                var valid = UserManager.IsLoginValid(UsernameTB.Text, PasswordTB.Text);

                if(valid)
                {
                    Session["Username"] = UsernameTB.Text;              
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx?message=" + UrlEncode("Login Successful!"));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddStartupAlert("Login attempt unsuccessful.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddStartupAlert(string key, string message)
        {
            ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
              key,
              "alert('" + message + "');",
              true);
        }
    }   
}
```

On your `~/Home.aspx` you should retrieve the username from the session variable, and show it to the user. Assuming you reuse the `AddStartupAlert` (might wanna move that to a helper class) you can do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        var username = Session["Username"];
        AddStartupAlert("WelcomeMessage", String.Format("Welcome to the site, {0}", username));
    }
}
```

Comment: I planned on getting rid of unnecessary stuff, i just wanted to know how to solve this particular problem. I'm new with ASP.NET so i'm taking things slowly. Still u pointed to me a lot of errors in my code, and given lots of advices. Thank you for that, i will definitely keep in mind all of this in future projects.

Comment: I get an error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (System.Type, string, string, bool)'. I'm not really sure how to fix it...